# Stop picking the same data twice

Tags: java

How exactly do I create my code from selecting the same item twice from the array?

Example:

it'll print something like this "Gloria
Gloria
la Cinq
Conflict"

How Do I stop it from doing that? Thanks in Advance

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The pump data consist of ONLY D24 PumpItUp charts

        Random rand = new Random();


        String[] PumpData = {"la Cinq", "Gloria", "Vanish", "Harma", "Conflict", "Sarabande", "Bedlam", "Final Audition", "Achluoias", "FFF", "Full moon", "Full moon FULL", "Annihilator" , "Creed FULL" , "BrainPower", "lolite", "Dement", "Destri", "Cross Soul", "TFTMN FULL", "Errorcode", "Dignity", "A Site De La Rue", "Trashy", "Paved Garden", "V3"};

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
            int rand_int = rand.nextInt(5);
            String ChooseDeath = (PumpData[rand_int]);
            System.out.println(ChooseDeath);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a set that keeps track of all **chooseDeath** String. Before printing it ,you can just verify whether the set contains it or not.
The question arises , what do you want to do in case a duplicate occurs, do you want to still print 4 words or less words .
I have shown the implementation which picks 4 words everytime.

```
public class SetTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // The pump data consist of ONLY D24 PumpItUp charts

      Random rand = new Random();


      String[] PumpData = {"la Cinq", "Gloria", "Vanish", "Harma", "Conflict", "Sarabande", "Bedlam", "Final Audition", "Achluoias", "FFF", "Full moon", "Full moon FULL", "Annihilator" , "Creed FULL" , "BrainPower", "lolite", "Dement", "Destri", "Cross Soul", "TFTMN FULL", "Errorcode", "Dignity", "A Site De La Rue", "Trashy", "Paved Garden", "V3"};
      Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++){
          int rand_int = rand.nextInt(5);
          String chooseDeath = (PumpData[rand_int]);
          if(!set.contains(chooseDeath))
          {
           set.add(chooseDeath); 
           System.out.println(chooseDeath);
          }
          else {
            i--; 
            continue; 
          }
          
      }
  }

}
```

this will give the following output :

```
Conflict
Gloria
Harma
Vanish
```

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of answers already. I just want to add a solution using `Stream`s.

```
new Random().ints(0, pumpData.length) // Create IntStream of random numbers between 0 and pumpData.length
    .distinct() // Remove duplicates from the stream
    .limit(4) // Limit stream to 4 numbers
    .mapToObj(i -> pumpData[i]) // Map IntStream to Stream<String> using the words in the array
    .forEach(System.out::println); // Print all the Strings
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of what you've already selected.  Something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();

String[] PumpData = {...};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int rand_int = rand.nextInt(5);
    while(visited.contains(rand_int))
    {
        rand_int = rand.nextInt(5);
    }
    System.out.println(PumpData[rand_int];
    visited.add(rand_int);
}
```

Comment: This wont always add unique strings : 
suppose your set contains 2 : 
when the random number is generated for the first time, it comes 2, 
then again the random number is generated, it comes 2, then the same string will be printed.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani This will elements from unique indexes, while loop ensures that already used index is never used again.

Comment: @cobp yes, realized it will always work

Answer (score 0):

You should store selected values in a Collection since collections has "is exists" or not function. I'd suggest you to store in a HashMap since it has O(1) access time or List.
 after each drawing you can question whether I selected this value before or not.